# Randon Algorithm to find if array have 1 in it

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I have a question where I have an array which have either only 0 in it or its half 0 and half 1. I need to sugest a random algorithm which can decide if the array have 1's inside of it.
its need to have 75% chance of success so it can only fail in 1/4 of the options and it needs to run in O(1).
the size of the array can be any n.

I would really appreciate some help or ideas in this question

Answer (score 0):

Assume n is even (otherwise you need to be more specific about what "half 0 and half 1 means").

Look at two (different) random elements in the array, and guess that the array is all zeroes if they're both zero. (If either of your elements is a one, you know that the array can't be all zeros, so must be half-and-half).

You always guess right when the array is all zero. When the array was half 1's and both of your selected elements are 0, you guess wrong. Assuming the array is half 1's, that happens with probability 1/2 * (n/2-1)/n = 1/4 - 1/2n. This is always less than 25%, so in the worst case, you succeed with at least 75% as required.

I note that there's not really any choice about what algorithm to use here -- O(1) means you can look at a bounded number of elements and the only ambiguous case is when you see all zeros. The only questions are to determine the number of elements you look at and the success probability.

Comment: thanks aren't necessary - but you can upvote and accept the answer if it solves your problem.